# Apt BADSIG error (Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key) while updating

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to update package's repository but APT gives me this error:

```
W: Errore GPG: http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: Le seguenti firme non erano valide: BADSIG XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key
 <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

The Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key is not valid. Can this problem make APT not to download important updates for my system?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you!

Comment: Trying to update package's repository to which repository? There may be a good reason for the error in that the repository you're trying to assign may contain malware.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to fix it using the following commands:

The easiest way:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com THE_KEY
```

Where "THE_KEY" is the repository key which you've masked with XXXXXXXXXXXX for some reason.

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

You can also use [Y PPA Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/y-ppa-manager-0092-released-with-new.html) which has options to automatically import missing GPG keys and fix BADSIG errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of other details (see comment), I'm thinking that the answer to your question is that the problem you describe is unlikely to cause you to miss important updates.