# BADSIG error with canonical archives repository

Tags: updates, xubuntu, gnupg

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.<br>GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

**I issued the following command:**

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
```

**And got the following message:**

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.VE2O5iyxt2 --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" 25 new signatures
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 25
```

**Tried the series of commands from this posting:**

[Apt BADSIG error (Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key) while updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210697/apt-badsig-error-ubuntu-archive-automatic-signing-key-while-updating)

**Tried using Y-PPA-Manager:**

Nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the PPA was outdated. Got the updated PPA, replaced the old with, reran update and this time no error messages.